# XML parsing text encoding problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to parse a XML feed with french accent like 'é' .
When I parse the XML I lost the accents...

What's wrong in my code...

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"my_xml_url"];
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSString *myData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
[parser parseXMLFile:myData];
```

And when I start parsing.....

```
- (void)parseXMLFile:(NSString *)data {
    BOOL success;

    //array for the ranking
    rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    index = 0;

    self.currentString = [NSMutableString string];
    storingCharacters = NO;
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[data data UsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    success = [parser parse];
    self.currentString = nil;

    //release memory
    [parser release];
}
```

I can't see where is the problem...

Thanks

Comment: NSXMLParser is event based. Can you show us where you are actually looking at the strings. It will be a method called something like parserFoundCharacters: or parserFoundCDATA:

Comment: IN -(void)parseXMLFile:(NSString *)data when I do NSLog(@"%@",data); I can't see the accents... It's before that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an encoding issue with stringWithContentsOfURL

Try:

```
NSError *lookupError = nil;
NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myUrl
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&lookupError];
```

Comment: This will work, as long as the XML data was encoded using UTF-8. You can't guarantee that, though, so this is a bit fragile. The solution I just posted below will work better with different file encodings.

Answer (score 0):

You're first reading the XML data and converting it to an NSString, then later converting that string back into data. As krtrego said, the to-string conversion is probably picking the wrong encoding. Instead, you should feed the raw data from the URL directly into NSXMLParser, which is smarter about being able to interpret the correct encoding (i.e. using the metadata at the top of the XML file.)

So instead use

```
NSData* myData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options: 0 error: &error];
```

then pass that data when initializing the NSXMLParser.